# How to define the stop mode command? (S08DZ96)

Tags: microcontroller, power-consumption, sleep, hcs08

I am using MC9S08DZ96 microcontroller and I using CodeWarrior version 11. I want to put the MCU to sleep mode(STOP3). In the CPU settings, I have changed the sleep mode setting and the relevant registers have been activated.

[image]

I know with the asm stop; command MCU goes to sleep mode. But it doesn't work. I think #define StopMode {asm STOP;} command, should be defined somewhere. Does anyone know how to define stop mode?
These are my registers:

```
void _EntryPoint(void)
{
  /* ### MC9S08DZ128_64 "Cpu" init code ... */
  /*  PE initialization code after reset */
  /* Common initialization of the write once registers */
  /* SOPT1: COPT=0,STOPE=1,SCI2PS=0,IIC1PS=0,??=0,??=0,??=0 */
  setReg8(SOPT1, 0x20U);  
              
  /* SOPT2: COPCLKS=0,COPW=0,??=0,ADHTS=0,??=0,MCSEL=0 */
  setReg8(SOPT2, 0x00U); 
               
  /* SPMSC1: LVWF=0,LVWACK=0,LVWIE=0,LVDRE=1,LVDSE=1,LVDE=1,??=0,BGBE=0 */
  setReg8(SPMSC1, 0x1CU); 
              
  /* SPMSC2: ??=0,??=0,LVDV=0,LVWV=0,PPDF=0,PPDACK=0,??=0,PPDC=0 */
  setReg8(SPMSC2, 0x00U);
               
  /*  System clock initialization */
  /*lint -save  -e923 Disable MISRA rule (11.3) checking. */

  if (*(uint8_t*)0xFFAFU != 0xFFU) {   
/* Test if the device trim value is stored on the specified address */
    MCGTRM = *(uint8_t*)0xFFAFU;       
/* Initialize MCGTRM register from a non volatile memory */
    MCGSC = *(uint8_t*)0xFFAEU;        
/* Initialize MCGSC register from a non volatile memory */
  }

  /*lint -restore Enable MISRA rule (11.3) checking. */
  /* MCGC2: BDIV=0,RANGE=0,HGO=0,LP=0,EREFS=0,ERCLKEN=0,EREFSTEN=1 */
  setReg8(MCGC2, 0x01U);               /* Set MCGC2 register */ 

  /* MCGC1: CLKS=0,RDIV=0,IREFS=1,IRCLKEN=1,IREFSTEN=1 */
  setReg8(MCGC1, 0x07U);               /* Set MCGC1 register */ 

  /* MCGC3: LOLIE=0,PLLS=0,CME=0,DIV32=0,VDIV=1 */
  setReg8(MCGC3, 0x01U);               /* Set MCGC3 register */ 

  /* MCGT: ??=0,??=0,DMX32=0,??=0,??=0,??=0,??=0,DRST_DRS=0 */
  setReg8(MCGT, 0x00U);                /* Set MCGT register */ 
  

  /*** End of PE initialization code after reset ***/
  /*lint -save  -e950 Disable MISRA rule (1.1) checking. */

  __asm   jmp _Startup ;               /* Jump to C startup code */
  /*lint -restore Enable MISRA rule (1.1) checking. */
}
```

Comment: Is this your reset vector? If it is, where is the SP set? If not, then who calls `_EntryPoint`?

Comment: @Lundin This is the function of the MCU clock registers, when I activate the `stop instruction enable` settings that I put in the picture. Some registers like **STOPE** are changed. In part **main()** , I don't call this function again.

Comment: I don't understand how to read this still, since `_Startup` is the CRT, meaning that `_EntryPoint` is either your reset vector, in which case it is incorrectly written, or it gets called from the reset vector, in which case it would be interesting to see the reset vector too.

Comment: Any reset vector for HCS08 must have a `TSX` asm instruction to set the SP and before you do this, you can't really execute C code.

Comment: You are right. I have a function for clock called **MCG_init()** . The `_EntryPoint` function is generated in the  **cpu.c**  file and this description is written above it.
Initializes the whole system like timing and so on. At the end of this function, the C startup is invoked to initialize stack, memory areas and so on.
This method is internal. It is used by Processor Expert only.

Comment: @Lundin I called `_EntryPoint` in `main()` but it still didn't work.

Comment: The SP must be set before calling `jmp` I believe. Anyway, this is probably not the cause of your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved. Instead of calling function `_EntryPoint` again, I wrote a function in file `main.c` and called this function before the command `asm(stop);`:

```
void stop3() {
    setReg8(SOPT1, 0x20U);                
    setReg8(SOPT2, 0x00U);                
    setReg8(SPMSC1, 0x1CU);               
    setReg8(SPMSC2, 0x00U);
}
```

Then, In `main()` I called the above function:

```
while(1) {
    if (T_Timer >= 10000) {
        stop3();
        asm(stop);
    }
}
```

With this, the normal consumption, which was 60 mA, was reduced to 40 mA, which, if we don't consider that the LEDs of the circuit are on, will significantly reduce the consumption.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. The rules allow that. Accepting your own answer (or any answer) adds credibility to the answer and that's something that others users will find useful in the future. It's a kind of evidence that "this worked".